# C# Parsing output for directory path

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get the path from the output of an application.
Here is the output sample:

[image]

How to I parse through the output for just the "C:\MyDir\Smith_Nathalie_20170428_140834479" and reuse it to tell storescu(sends dicom files) what path to look in.

ex: Storesu 106 +sd "C:\MyDir\Smith_Nathalie_20170428_140834479"

any help would be great.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question

Comment: `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(myFullPath);`

Comment: I included a pix of the output. The output does not format correctly when copy n pasted. hope this clear up things. thx again.

Comment: @ChristopherDoty I've updated my answer for your latest edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName()`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx

**EDIT (again)**

You could use a Regex for parsing the filename out of your string.  For the string you are showing, I'd recommend having the Regex look for the message about creating the new subdirectory.  It would look like this

```
        string directoryName = string.Empty;
        string inputtext = @"creating new subdirectory for study: C:\MyDir\Smith_Nathalie_20170428_140834479 I: storing DICOM file: C:\MyDir\Smith_Nathalie_20170428_140834479\DXm.1.2.840.113681.2206606139.739.3355346425.685.1 I: Received Store Request: MsgID 2, (DXm) RECV: ..................................................................................... I: storing DICOM file: C:\MyDir\Smith_Nathalie_20170428_140834479\DXm.1.2.840.113681.2206606139.739.3355346425.687.1 I: Received Store Request: MsgID 3, (DXm)";

        System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matchCol = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(inputtext, @"(?<=creating new subdirectory for study: )[^\s]+(?=\s)");

        if (matchCol.Count > 0)
            directoryName = matchCol[0].Value;
```